# Как сделать редирект с поддомена на другой поддомен?

Tags: .htaccess

Как сделать редирект с http://poddomen1.site.ru/ сюда http://poddomen2.site.ru/ и для всех нижестоящих разделов и страниц?
Пока вышел на такой вариант

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^poddomen1(\.site\.ru.*)
 RewriteRule ^poddomen1(.*)$ ^poddomen2($1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^poddomen1\.site\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://poddomen2.site.ru%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Подробнее: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323366/how-can-i-redirect-from-one-subdomain-to-another-in-htaccess

Проверить: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/